# Unable to cast object of type 'System.Byte[]' to type 'System.IConvertible'

Tags: c#

```
FMT fmt=new FMT();    

public void ReadFmtHeader()
{
    fmt.s_Sub_Chunk_ID_1 = reader.ReadBytes(4);
    fmt.ui_Sub_Chunk_Size_ID_1 = reader.ReadBytes(4);
    fmt.us_Audio_Format = reader.ReadBytes(2);
    fmt.us_Num_Channels = reader.ReadBytes(2);
    fmt.ui_Sample_Rate = reader.ReadBytes(4);
    fmt.ui_Byte_Rate = reader.ReadBytes(4);
    fmt.us_Block_Align = reader.ReadBytes(2);
    fmt.us_Bits_Per_Sample = reader.ReadBytes(2);

    if (Convert.ToInt32(fmt.ui_Sub_Chunk_Size_ID_1) == 18)// Exception thrown on this line
    {
        // Read any extra values
        int fmtExtraSize = reader.ReadInt16();
        reader.ReadBytes(fmtExtraSize);
    }
}
```

I am trying to read a wave file, and then recreate it using header info and save to file. 
I don't know what is the problem. Can anybody help me with this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can't convert a `byte[]` to an `int` using `Convert.ToInt32`; you need to [use a `BitConverter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384066.aspx).

Comment: So what is the difference between BitConverter.ToInt32 and Convert.ToInt32 ?

Comment: The difference is that the `BitConverter` is built to do exactly what you're trying to do: take an array of bytes and convert them into their integral representation. `Convert.Int32` is meant for converting anything that's already an integer, or can be converted to an integer using the `IConvertible` interface.